# How can I update my UI with data passed back from a second View Controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface

I'm working on a small stock app that displays stock based on the price the user selected. Initially when the app loads I display all the stocks. However, I implemented a filter, when the user taps on a text field it segues to a second view controller and the user have to select the price they want by selecting a radio button. I've successfully passed the user input back using protocols and delegate and saving it to a priceTarget variable, However, I'm not sure how to update the UI with the new price. I'm assuming I have to reload my tableView and fetch the data again with the updated price. Can someone offer a few suggestions?

```
// pass user input back
 @IBAction func priceBtnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

        switch sender.tag {
        case 1:
            delegate?.passPrice(price: oneDollarPriceLabel.text!)
        case 2:
            delegate?.passPrice(price: twoDollarPriceLabel.text!)
        case 3:
            delegate?.passPrice(price: threeDollarPriceLabel.text!)
        case 4:
            delegate?.passPrice(price: fourDollarPriceLabel.text!)
        case 5:
            delegate?.passPrice(price: fiveDollarPriceLabel.text!)
        default:
            print("Problem in priceBtnTap()")
        }

      func passPrice(price: String) {
        priceTarget = price
        print(priceTarget)
      }

      var priceTarget = "10"

//MARK: - Fetch stockDta
    func fetchData()  {
        guard let  urlString = URL(string: "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock-screener?sector=technology&priceLowerThan=\(priceTarget)&exchange=NYSE,NASDAQ,AMEX&limit=100&apikey=\(Api.key)") else {
            
            fatalError("Wrong endpoint")
        }
        
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlString) { [self] (data, _, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("opps, we have a problem")
                return
            }
            if let payload = data {
                guard let stockInfo = try? JSONDecoder().decode([StockData].self, from: payload) else {
                    print("issue decoding data")
                    return
                }
                self.stockArray.append(contentsOf: stockInfo)
                
                //MARK: - iterate over the stock data and save all the stock symbols in a new array
                for stockSymbol in stockInfo {
                    self.stockSymbolArray.append(stockSymbol.symbol!)
                }
                
                //MARK: - Call the fetchStockChangeData() and pass the stockSymbolArray as a paramater of the function
                fetchStockChangeData(stock: stockSymbolArray)
                
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tabelview.reloadData()
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
```

Comment: When the user selects a price, how exactly does this change the data itself in the previous view controller? Must you re-fetch the data through the network or can you manipulate the existing data to reflect the selected price? Your task is to update the data as efficiently as possible and then either reload the entire table or individual cells.

Comment: once they select a price the data have to be re-fetch. I didn't cache the data because stock prices tend to fluctuate.

Comment: So you already fetch this data periodically to update the UI and now you just need to update it again after the user selects a price. Then simply call `fetchData()` in the `passPrice(price:)` method, no? I don't see where you input price into `dataTask`, however, so I'm confused as to how the user's selected-price requires you to re-fetch the data through the network.

Comment: so initially when the app loads the stock price is hardcoded to only show stocks with a price tag of $10.00, and that variable is what is pass into my URL link to fetch the stock, once the user checks the radio button EX $1.00, that $1.00 is passed back and capture in the price variable, and that price variable changes from $10.00 to now $1.00. So at this point, I'm thinking I now have to re-fetch the data with the new price and update the table view. or maybe my thought process is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thought process is correct. When the user taps the button and the delegate calls `passPrice(price:)`, simply call `fetchData()` at the end of that task.

Keep in mind that the cells the table view has on screen when the button is tapped is specifically rendering what's in `stockArray`. Therefore, be careful when you modify `stockArray` because if the new data fetch results in an array of a different size or the parsing of results is relatively time consuming all while the user is actively scrolling through the table view, it could have unwanted side effects such as curiously-rendered cells or even a fatal out-of-bounds error which would crash the app. Therefore, I would suggest creating a local array (local to the scope of the closure) within the data return that you populate with results that you then hand off to `stockArray` before reloading the table view:

```
if let payload = data {
    var tempArray = [StockData]() // instantiate local/temp array
    // modify temp array safely without fear of side effects           
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.stockArray = tempArray // hand off to data source right before reloading
    self.tabelview.reloadData()
}
```